# Ubuntu 16.4 | Eclipse show a white window at the start-up

Tags: eclipse

today I downloaded Eclipse, but unfortunately it opens with a white screen and does not load! Help!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xty4q.png)

Comment: Is there any weird output if you run it from terminal?

Comment: I need to try. Wait a second.

Comment: nothing, only the weird window :(

Comment: Have a look at this [how to debug eclipse crash on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569849/how-to-debug-eclipse-crash-on-startup)